# jclouds with OpenStack => java.util.NoSuchElementException: apiType compute not found in catalog []

Tags: java, openstack, jclouds

Java jclouds API fails to connect to an OpenStack provider.

Exception is thrown with the following message: java.util.NoSuchElementException: apiType compute not found in catalog [].

Other APIs (python-novaclient, ruby-fog) work just fine, so the problem looks language (API)-specific.

```
import static com.google.common.io.Closeables.closeQuietly;

import java.io.Closeable;
import java.util.Set;

import org.jclouds.ContextBuilder;
import org.jclouds.compute.ComputeService;
import org.jclouds.compute.ComputeServiceContext;
import org.jclouds.compute.domain.ComputeMetadata;
import org.jclouds.logging.slf4j.config.SLF4JLoggingModule;
import org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.NovaApi;
import org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.NovaAsyncApi;
import org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.domain.Server;
import org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.features.ServerApi;
import org.jclouds.rest.RestContext;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet;
import com.google.inject.Module;

public class jcloudsOpenStack implements Closeable {
   private ComputeService compute;
   private RestContext nova;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      jcloudsOpenStack jcloudOpenStack = new jcloudsOpenStack();

      try {
         jcloudOpenStack.init();
         jcloudOpenStack.listServers();
         jcloudOpenStack.close();
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      finally {
         jcloudOpenStack.close();
      }
   }

   private void init() {
      Iterable modules = ImmutableSet. of(new SLF4JLoggingModule());

      String provider = "openstack-nova";
      String identity = "...";   // login name
      String password = "...";   // password

      ComputeServiceContext context = ContextBuilder.newBuilder(provider)
            .endpoint("https://UltiCloud.com:5000/v2.0/")
            .credentials(identity, password)
            .modules(modules)
            .buildView(ComputeServiceContext.class);
      compute = context.getComputeService();
      nova = context.unwrap();
   }

   private void listServers() {
      Set<? extends ComputeMetadata> nodes = compute.listNodes();
      System.out.println(nodes.size());
   }

   public void close() {
      closeQuietly(compute.getContext());
   }
}
```

Any help or a hint is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem in last few days, and finally i got this resolved.
you should use"username:tenantname" for parameters 'identity' of 'credentials' function.
if you use "username" instead of "tenantname:username", jclouds would query tokens only instead of querying endpoint-list after token-querying, and the exception been thrown.

looks like this:

```
  ComputeServiceContext context = ContextBuilder.newBuilder(provider)
        .endpoint("https://UltiCloud.com:5000/v2.0/")
        .credentials("admin:admin", "123456")
        .modules(modules)
        .buildView(ComputeServiceContext.class);
```

not like this:

```
  ComputeServiceContext context = ContextBuilder.newBuilder(provider)
        .endpoint("https://UltiCloud.com:5000/v2.0/")
        .credentials("admin", "123456")
        .modules(modules)
        .buildView(ComputeServiceContext.class);
```

Hope this could help you guys

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the proper dependencies to run this. It's easiest to use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) to get them.

The bare minimum you need for the example above is the openstack-nova dependency. To get it make a file called pom.xml and copy in this code.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <properties>
    <jclouds.version>1.7.0</jclouds.version>
  </properties>
  <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.examples</groupId>
  <artifactId>openstack-examples</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.api</groupId>
      <artifactId>openstack-nova</artifactId>
      <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Then run `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies "-DoutputDirectory=./lib"` that will download all of the dependencies you need to run your example.

Don't forget to include the lib dir in your path when you compile or run it like `java -classpath ".:lib/*" jcloudsOpenStack`

A more complete pom.xml file for working with all of the OpenStack services supported in jclouds follows.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven 4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <properties>
    <jclouds.version>1.7.0</jclouds.version>
  </properties>
  <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.examples</groupId>
  <artifactId>openstack-examples</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- jclouds dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.driver</groupId>
      <artifactId>jclouds-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.driver</groupId>
      <artifactId>jclouds-sshj</artifactId>
      <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- OpenStack dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.api</groupId>
      <artifactId>openstack-keystone</artifactId>
      <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.api</groupId>
      <artifactId>openstack-nova</artifactId>
      <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.api</groupId>
      <artifactId>swift</artifactId>
      <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.api</groupId>
      <artifactId>openstack-cinder</artifactId>
      <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.api</groupId>
      <artifactId>openstack-trove</artifactId>
      <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.labs</groupId>
      <artifactId>openstack-glance</artifactId>
      <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.labs</groupId>
      <artifactId>openstack-marconi</artifactId>
      <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.labs</groupId>
      <artifactId>openstack-neutron</artifactId>
      <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- 3rd party dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.25</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: I have all these. If I had not, I would not have been able to compile the code, which I was able to do. I will check if I have everything you mentioned though, thanks.

Comment: I ran your example exactly as is against a DevStack Havana deployment of mine and it worked just fine. Hope it's working for you too.

Comment: Thanks, so far it does not, but we are working on it. Good to know it works for you.

Comment: @user2436366 did you ever get this resolved? I'm using a rackspace private cloud and running into the same issue

Comment: This is a common issue. Have a look at http://jclouds.apache.org/reference/troubleshooting/ to see if that helps.